# Как получить данные c mysql по дате за вчера

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Задача, вывести данные из таблицы по дате, за вчерашний день.

Мой запрос

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM ugc_users WHERE dateRegistration BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE AND CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 6 - WEEKDAY(CURRENT_DATE) DAY
```

Получаю результат как за сегодня.

Как правильно составить запрос  ?

Comment: `BETWEEN {вчера} AND {сегодня - 1 микросекунда}`, а не то, что в запросе. Но лучше два неравенства, чем BETWEEN.

Comment: Не совсем понял

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT COUNT(id) 
FROM ugc_users 
WHERE dateRegistration >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 DAY
  AND dateRegistration < CURRENT_DATE
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы.